# How do you properly use ChannelAPI to send a file from wear to mobile and vice versa?

Tags: wear-os, file-transfer, channel-api

I am trying to record audio on the wear and send it to the mobile and vice versa using the Channel API. However I can't find a working example of how to write this. Can anyone help? Thanks.

Comment: Question should have 
    …Minimal – Use as little code as possible that still produces the same problem
    …Complete – Provide all parts needed to reproduce the problem
    …Verifiable - Test the code you're about to provide to make sure it reproduces the problem
 http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: A complete example would be best.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [WearCompanionLibrary](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-WearCompanionLibrary) that provides an API for that. The sample [WclDemoSample](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-WclDemoSample) uses that library and one of the features shown there is exactly that; it sends the audio stream (captured from microphone) from a wear device to the connected phone in real-time, using ChannelApi. If you don't want to use the library, you can take a look inside and see how it is done.

Comment: This is great! But I don't want to send the audio file in real time as my app does some simple pre-processing on the watch before sending the file as a whole. How could I implement something like that using this library?

Comment: If you read the documentation in the library (or even look through the sample demo app), you'll see a section on how to transfer a file using this library.